# How to find the Mathematica command for the function $a_k?$

Tags: special-functions, coding-style, command-line

I am trying to find the $n$-th derivative of $\csc(m\pi)$, so I took few cases:

for simplicity let $x=\cot(m\pi)$ and $y=\csc(m\pi)$,

$$\frac{d^0}{dm^0}\csc(m\pi)=\pi^0(\color{red}{1}x^0y^1)$$

$$\frac{d^1}{dm^1}\csc(m\pi)=-\pi^1 (\color{red}{1}x^1y^1)$$

$$\frac{d^2}{dm^2}\csc(m\pi)=\pi^2(\color{red}{1}x^2y^1+\color{red}{1}x^0y^3)$$

$$\frac{d^3}{dm^3}\csc(m\pi)=-\pi^3(\color{red}{1}x^3y^1+\color{red}{5}x^1y^3)$$

$$\frac{d^4}{dm^4}\csc(m\pi)=\pi^4(\color{red}{1}x^4y^1+\color{red}{18}x^2y^3+\color{red}{5}x^0y^5)$$

$$\frac{d^5}{dm^5}\csc(m\pi)=-\pi^5(\color{red}{1}x^5y^1+\color{red}{58}x^3y^3+\color{red}{61}x^1y^5)$$

$$\frac{d^6}{dm^6}\csc(m\pi)=\pi^6(\color{red}{1}x^6y^1+\color{red}{179}x^4y^3+\color{red}{479}x^2y^5+\color{red}{61}x^0y^7)$$

and saw that

$$\frac{d^n}{dm^n}\csc(m\pi)=(-\pi)^n\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor{n/2}\rfloor}\color{red}{a_k} x^{n-2k}
y^{2k+1}.$$

Luckily, in the following photo

[image]

in page 21 of this [paper](https://reader.elsevier.com/reader/sd/pii/S0097316516300048?token=2B8C9976CE219725388A8CD165207011FF01598ADC1046DC4F6F5C938B07C9CED4426C1A80EAC833D6FD61D25FA508B8&originRegion=us-east-1&originCreation=20220307231514), I noticed that $\color{red}{a_k}$ matches the terms in the table above assuming $t=1$.

**Question**: Does the table help us find the Mathematica command for the function of $\color{red}{a_k}$?

Note that rpk-polynomial $P^{rpk}_n(t)$ stands for the right-peak polynomial.

Thanks,

Comment: People here generally like users to post code as *Mathematica* code instead of just images or TeX, so they can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you. You may find [the meta Q&A, How to copy code from Mathematica so it looks good on this site,](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: Try `D[Csc[Pi m], {m, n}]`. -- I suppose you mean $a_{n,k}$?

Comment: I don't see the point of voluntarily helping people who are unwilling to make it easy for me to copy their problem and paste it into Mathematica. In my experience, they are often difficult to work with. Not that it really matters in this case, since @Domen has given an answer.

Comment: A way to get your xy polynomials and convert them to the t polys: `Expand@Table[Normal@Series[D[Csc[Pi m], {m, n}] /. {Sin[m \[Pi]] -> 1/y, Csc[m \[Pi]] -> y, Cot[m \[Pi]] -> x, Tan[m \[Pi]] -> 1/x, Cos[m \[Pi]] -> x/y, Sec[m \[Pi]] -> y/x}, {x, 0, n}, {y, 0, n + 1}]/y, {n, 5}] /. {x -> 1, y^p_ :> t^(p/2)}`

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the necessary code can be found online https://oeis.org/A008971 and is pretty clear that there is no built-in function that produces the desired outcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there is an in-built function but you can easily make one yourself by using Mathematica code from OEIS [A008971](https://oeis.org/A008971).

```
t[n_, 0] = 1;
t[n_, k_] /; k > Floor[n/2] = 0;
t[n_, k_] /; k <= Floor[n/2] := 
  t[n, k] = (2 k + 1) t[n - 1, k] + (n - 2 k + 1) t[n - 1, k - 1];

rpk[n_] := FromDigits[Reverse@Table[t[n, k], {k, 0, n/2}], t]
```

Let's reproduce the table from the paper:

```
TableForm[Table[{n, rpk[n] // Expand}, {n, 0, 9}], 
 TableHeadings -> {None, {"n", "\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(P\), 
 \(n\), \(rpk\)]\)(t)"}}]
```

[image: rpk polynomials]

Comment: Or `FromDigits[Table[t[n,k], {k,n,0,-1}], t]` if one wants to stick to system-level functions

Comment: Thank you so much (+1). All i needed is $t(n,k)=(2k+1)t(n-1,k)+(n-2k+1)t(n-1,k-1)$ where $t(n,0)=1$.